# run length encoding on dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply, lapply

I can find the run length encoding on a single vector using the following formula

```
dat <-c(1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
dat1<-data.frame(dat)    
run <- rle(dat1$dat>0)
duration <- rep(run$lengths, run$lengths)
duration

#[1]  4  4  4  4  1  1  5  5  5  5  5 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

the problem is i need to create the same function on a data frame to create a duration for each column.

```
dat2<-data.frame(dat,dat,dat)
apply(tt,2,rle)

$dat
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 4 1 1 5 10
  values : num [1:5] 1 0 1 0 1

$dat.1
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 4 1 1 5 10
  values : num [1:5] 1 0 1 0 1

$dat.2
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 4 1 1 5 10
  values : num [1:5] 1 0 1 0 1
```

I get a list after applying this. **but i cannot figure out how to create a duration matrix for each vector to output a duration data.frame.**

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be the following:

```
dat <-c(1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
dat2<-data.frame(dat,dat,dat)
```

The only thing I did was to wrap you single vector code inside the function `lapply` and then convert the output into a data.frame. And you get the duration for each column. The output is a data.frame.

```
dat3 <- data.frame(lapply(dat2, function(x) {
  run <- rle(x>0)
  duration <- rep(run$lengths, run$lengths)
  duration
}))
```

As another option you could use  `inverse.rle` as per @akrun 's comment:

```
data.frame(lapply(dat2, function(x) inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x>0), 
                                                            values <- lengths))))
```

Output:

```
> dat3
   dat dat.1 dat.2
1    4     4     4
2    4     4     4
3    4     4     4
4    4     4     4
5    1     1     1
6    1     1     1
7    5     5     5
8    5     5     5
9    5     5     5
10   5     5     5
11   5     5     5
12  10    10    10
13  10    10    10
14  10    10    10
15  10    10    10
16  10    10    10
17  10    10    10
18  10    10    10
19  10    10    10
20  10    10    10
21  10    10    10
```

Comment: @akrun That's a nice one! Don't you want to add it as an answer?

Comment: It's okay.  Your answer is very good.  You can add this as an option. Thanks.